# How to send multiple response using nock if there is no request body

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking, nock

I am calling a streaming api http://dummy-streaming-api/customer-details which accepts post requests and sends some data. It does not require any request body.
I want to mock the response using [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) in a Node.js application for unit tests.
I already have a test case for happy journey in which nock intercepts the request and sends 200 along with some data.

```
nock('http://dummy-streaming-api')
    .persist()
    .get('/customer-details')
    .reply(200,dummyResponse)
```

How do I write a nock which sends 500 or 404, as I do not have request body to differentiate between 2 requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TLDR;

I'd suggest removing `.persist()` and setting up nock in each test with the response you want.

#### Details

The `.persist()` call makes that particular nock exist for multiple calls in a row. There are a lot of features (eg. sending different replies, or scope.isDone()) that you miss out on by persisting a nock, and persisting opens up to some hard-to-find bugs.

I'd suggest removing `.persist()` and instead creating a new nock in each test, and running `nock.cleanAll()` in your afterEach. This gets you better readability on the current state of nock and what each test is really testing.

#### Example:

```
afterEach(() => nock.cleanAll())

it('should call the endpoint', async () => {
  const streamApiNock = nock('http://dummy-streaming-api')
    .get('/customer-details')
    .reply(200, dummyResponse)

  const response = await myCallToApi(url)
  expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200)
  expect(streamApiNock.isDone()).to.be.true()
}

it('should handle an error from the endpoint', async () => {
  const streamApiNock = nock('http://dummy-streaming-api')
    .get('/customer-details')
    .reply(500, {err: 'my error'})

  const response = await myCallToApi(url) 
  // this might need a try/catch or an expect().to.reject() or whatever
  // depending on what testing lib you're using

  expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(500)
  expect(streamApiNock.isDone()).to.be.true()
}
```

If you have multiple tests that require the same nock response and don't want to keep writing the code, I'd put those all in a `describe('200 response')` block, put the nock call in the `beforeEach()`, and a `nock.cleanAll()` in the `afterEach()`. That way, testing state is obvious in each section of code and gets cleaned up in a way that can prevent hard-to-detect bugs for other developers.

If you need multiple calls in the *same test*, like if you were testing retry functionality on your internal fetch function or something, I'd suggest calling nock twice (and using `chaining` or `.times()` for cleaner syntax). See docs: [Intercepting multiple calls](https://github.com/nock/nock#read-this---about-interceptors)

Example:

```
afterEach(() => nock.cleanAll())

// Sets up nock twice to check for rate limiting/retry functionality
it('should retry 3 times on 500', async () => {
  nock('http://dummy-streaming-api')
    .get('/customer-details')
    .reply(500, err)
    .get('/customer-details')
    .reply(500, err)
    .get('/customer-details')
    .reply(200, payload)
  
  await myRetryFunction();

  expect(nock.isDone()).to.be.true()
}

it('should retry 3 times on 500', async () => {
  nock('http://dummy-streaming-api')
    .get('/customer-details')
    .times(2)
    .reply(500, err)
    .get('/customer-details')
    .reply(200, payload)
  
  await myRetryFunction();

  expect(nock.isDone()).to.be.true()
}
```

Chaining: [Chaining](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock#chaining)

Docs for `nock.persist()`: [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock#persist)